# Lock acquire and release

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, locking

I am going through the operating system course online (youtube, UC Berkeley) and while discussing the mechanism to ensure Atomicity of operations between threads that share resources, there was the following slide

The professor talks about making the acquire and release part of lock variable atomic, by disabling interrupts while checking the lock value.

The code to access the shared state is as follows for each thread

```
milkLock.acquire()
if(no milk) getMilk()
milkLock.release()
```

From the implementation of acquire and release in the slide below, I dont understand that when a thread comes in and sees that the lock is already acquired, it will go to sleep. Now when the other thread releases the lock, how will this thread acquire the lock again, because it is not calling milkLock.acquire() when it wakes up.

[image: Locks Implementation]

Comment: Some text inside `Release` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Thread Control Block (TCB).

Also https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall09/cps110/slides/threads2.3.ppt this slide can be helpful about the topic.